# Localization of Object in Rviz and Gazebo

Tags: ros2, sensors, ros-humble, depth, 3d-object-recognition

I have a Simulated Robot in Gazebo and Rviz and i want to use a Camera and Bring an Object present in the Real World into Rviz, so that the Robot can see this Object.  I would like to represent this Object as 3D in Rviz.

Is this Possible? Because I only have a simulated Robot. How should i get this? Which is the best Sensor to use other than Camera, if needed?

System:
Ubuntu 22.04
Ros Humble